# Is it possible to add UITableView within a UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Insted of scroll view i used Tableview controller, inside Tableview controller i desined by adding collection view, textfield also i want to add table view inside it.

I implemeted but it crashes the app beacuse of parent table view. Any solution?

Comment: *Yes it's doable. It's crashing may be because the way you add is wrong* ***Please post the code so that we can tell you what is going wrong***

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom cell with tableView(Autoheight TableView) inside it. Add cell to your TableViewController.

1. Custom Cell with AutoHeightTableView
2. Set isScrolling, bounces of AutoHeightTable to false
3. Register  custom cell to TableViewController
4. Load custom cell table data

   ```
    final class AutoHeightTableView: UITableView {

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        return self.contentSize
    }

    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet{
            UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   }